# htacces redirection if the url doesn't have .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wish to redirect all page requests if

(1) Current URL doesn't have .php extension

(2) Current Page is not the Site Home (ie www.site.com )

Example:

http://site.com/robin to profile.php?screen_name=robin

Can someone suggests the htaccess to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This site should give some hints:

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

an excerpt from there:

> **Changed file extension?**
>
> This example is perfect if you've
>   decided to switch to .php from .html
>   pages. It will look for any .html page
>   and redirect it to .php (ie
>   http://www.example.com/yourpage.html
>   and redirect it to
>   http://www.example.com/yourpage.php).
>   Now, be careful with this, it does
>   mean any html page. I did this on one
>   of my sites and had totally forgotten
>   I had an iframe with .html content on
>   some pages... I didn't notice for
>   weeks that it was broken :S. So learn
>   from my mistake ;-) check, double
>   check, then check again.
>
> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com$1.php
> ```

You can put arbitrary regular expressions as parameter to Redirectmatch, so you need to add a regular expression which matches '".php" not last of line'. I am only a neophyte of RegExes myelf, so i do not provide an example yet. Check for a later update -have to do some experimating.

Comment: Another condition is, the current page is not the site index page.. Because index page may somewhere doesn't have .php extension (www.site.com)